# Show that the sequence $(x_{n})$ given by $x_n = \sqrt{n+k} - \sqrt{n}, k \in \mathbb{R}$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am currently studying for the math GRE subject test and am brushing up on sequences - this is an example given in the Princeton review. The author justifies the answer using the following theorems:

- (1) For any $k \in \mathbb{R}, (a_n)\rightarrow A \Rightarrow (ka_{n}) \rightarrow kA$.
- (2) For any $k \in \mathbb{R}^{+}, \dfrac{1}{n^{k}} \rightarrow 0$.
- (3) The squeeze theorem.

Ok, I follow the argument up to a point.

We have
$$
x_n = \sqrt{n+k} - \sqrt{n} = \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{n+k} + \sqrt{n}}
$$

Note that for any $n \geq -k$, $\sqrt{n+k} + \sqrt{n} \geq \sqrt{n}$, so

$$
\dfrac{k}{\sqrt{n+k} + \sqrt{n}} \leq \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

The author then lets $(a_{n})$ be the sequence where every term is $0$ and $b_{n} = \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{n}}$. Note $b_{n} \rightarrow 0$ by (1) and (2). He then claims that since $(a_{n})\leq(x_{n})\leq(b_{n})$, then $(x_{n}) \rightarrow 0$ by the squeeze theorem. But is the inequality $(a_{n})\leq(x_{n})$ necessarily true? Can't we have
$\dfrac{k}{\sqrt{n+k} + \sqrt{n}} < 0$ since each real number (other than $0$) has both a positive and a negative square root? Or do we just ignore the negative values, kind of like when we graph $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $x\ge0$, then $\sqrt x$ is the non-negative square root of $c$.

Comment: On an even more basic level, $x_n = \sqrt{n+k}-\sqrt{n}$ is meaningless as a real number unless you fix an interpretation of the square root function.

Comment: @AnotherUser:   Did you mean *x* where you typed *c*?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$
> x_n = \sqrt{n+k} - \sqrt{n} = \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{n+k} + \sqrt{n}}
> $$

If $k<0$, then $x_n<0$. Further, when $n$ is sufficiently large, such that $n+k\ge0$, we have

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+k} + \sqrt{n}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\Leftrightarrow\dfrac{k}{\sqrt{n+k} + \sqrt{n}}\ge\frac{k}{\sqrt n}$$

hence,

$$\frac{k}{\sqrt n}\le x_n<0$$

By squeeze theorem,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n =0$$